# How to enable events after using jquery.preventdefault?

Tags: jquery, horizontal-scrolling, keydown, preventdefault

How can I enable events after using jquery.preventdefault?

I have this code to prevent the document from scrolling to left and right on the keycode below,

```
$('body').keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 39 || e.keyCode === 37) {
        e.preventDefault();
       // return false;
    }
});
```

Then I have a button to enable the keycodes above and let the page to be scrolled again,

```
     $('#pbCloseBtn').click(function(){
        $('body').keydown(function(e){
            if (e.keyCode === 39 || e.keyCode === 37) {
               e.bind('scroll');
               return true;
            }
        });
    });
```

But it won't work after preventing the page from scrolling.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could unbind the functionality from the two keys at the start, then on your `#pbCloseBtn` function rebind like you're currently doing.

Comment: `e.bind('scroll')` gives `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'bind'` because you're calling it on the event object, but in any case `.bind()` doesn't create an event or cause an event to start happening, it binds a handler to an existing event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to unbind existing handler

```
$('#pbCloseBtn').click(function(){
    $('body').unbind('keydown'); // <-- removes previous handler
});
```

Comment: From the documentation of unbind : *"As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to attach and remove event handlers on elements"*. See my answer.

Comment: No, calling `.e.bind('scroll')` gives an error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'bind'`. The `.unbind()` (or `.off()`) part is enough on its own.

Comment: @nnnnnn: you're correct. Didn't see what that function was doing. Fixed it

Comment: @dystroy: not sure which jquery version he's using, tried to follow exisiting logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use on and [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) :

```
var preventScroll = function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 39 || e.keyCode === 37) {
        e.preventDefault();
       // return false;
    }
};
$('body').on('keydown', preventScroll);
$('#pbCloseBtn').click(function(){
    $('body').off('keydown', preventScroll);
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/otawov/3/)